# XPath Expression to check if xml contains key and value

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a xml as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LogSpeech>
   <ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>
   <SensitiveData2>Credit Card Data Is Here</SensitiveData2>
</LogSpeech>
```

I need to check using xpath whether the tag "ReturnCode" and its value "0" exists or not. For example, contains("ReturnCode","0"). So far I am able to get the element as `'<ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>'` using xpath expression as `//*[local-name()='ReturnCode'][text()='0']`. What would be the exact contains xpath query which will return some boolean value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap your original XPath in [`boolean()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean) function, or more briefly as follow -assuming no default namespace involved- :

```
boolean(//ReturnCode[.=0])
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester.com demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/f74827c9099160a702e5c889b671315a)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
true
```